# Why does a property array always return null in template

Tags: angular, angular7

I have the following code in my angular template

```
{{myObject.dayList|async|json}}
```

However this always displays "null" in the page despite the object being populated in the component. This is proven by the fact that I can log it to the console and it has populated data.

If I do

```
{{myObject|async|json}}
```

It displays the json for the object including the populated dayList array!

What is going on?

This is myObject

```
export class myObject{
    public timetableItems:TimetableItemViewModel[];
    public dayList:number[];
}
```

Contents of log

> {dayList: Array(1), timetableItems: Array(2)}dayList:
>   [1]timetableItems: (2) [{…}, {…}]0: {assignedClass: {…}, assignedRoom:
>   {…}, assignedPeriod: {…}}1: assignedClass: {classId: 1027, className:
>   "English1", subjectId: 2004, periodCount: 1, assets:
>   Array(1), …}assignedPeriod: {periodId: 1006, dayNumber: 1,
>   periodTypeId: 2, accountId: "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
>   periodNumber: 2}assignedRoom: {roomId: 19, roomName: "Room1",
>   subjectId: 2004, assets: Array(1), capacity: 20, …}**proto**:
>   Objectlength: 2__proto__: Array(0)**proto**: Object

Comment: Can you share it in stackbiltz or console.log(myObject) after subscribing and show output

Comment: I have updated the question with the log details

Comment: Is this log of `myObject`?

Comment: Nope, my bad. Just updating now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your log has `dayList` not `dayItems`. Try :

```
`<div *ngIf="myObject| async; let obj">
    {{obj.dayList | json}}
 </div>`
```

Note: Modified answer based on  Cristian's comment

Comment: It wouldn't work anyway. `dayList` isn't neither an observable nor a promise

Comment: I am assuming it is an observable with Type `myObject` else why would he has used `async`

Comment: It was supposed to be dayList. I typed it wrong. Now updated.

Comment: MyObject is an Observable in the component. Does dayList need to be an observable too?

Comment: No.. Can you share it in stackbiltz

Comment: Actually yes. If `myObject` is an observable and `dayList` isn't, you need to write `(myObject | async).dayList`

Comment: It is a rather large application and I also do not have a github account at the moment. I will update the question with some more detail.

Comment: @Cristian Traina. That is it! thanks. If you add it as an answer I will mark it as correct.

Comment: Yeah.. right! got it! soulution can be this: `<div *ngIf="myObject| async; let obj">
 {{obj.dayList | json}}
</div>`

Comment: I rewrote my comment as answer, in order to make the thread more complete. Feel free to accept @AdritaSharma answer instead, her answer is correct too and she has been faster

Answer (score 1):

The `async` pipe works only if the object that you are piping is a `Promise` or an `Observable`. In your case, if `myObject` is an `Observable` but `myObject.dayList` isn't, you might need to get the async value of `myObject` and then read the property `dayList` from it:

```
 {{ (myObject | async).dayList }}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `myObject` is an observable, so this needs to be used in the `async` pipe, because it expects an observable:

```
{{ (myObject | async)?.dayList | json }}
```

The safe navigation operator `?.` makes sure you won't get a null pointer error